# Trying to write App Script for sheets/forms to automate email response

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form and sheet but I'm not sure which is better to use to pull data from or create the trigger of form submit.

I am trying to create an email response to a form that is based on a google doc with images and text and will pull the name and responses from the form (or sheet).
Here are the work files. I will need to add this script to a different form/sheet later.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MhHOPjMD0JwVgP98majrKBPk-Cf1_Uwn?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an existing template for something related to what you are asking for in this Google developer documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/content-signup where you can easily make a copy of the file and change the values based on what you need.

This is basically allowing you to send emails from a trigger "onFormSubmit" based on what people filled in the Google form. Please let me know if you actually need the full code though! Or what exactly you are trying to achieve if the template is not working for you.

Comment: I have this code and am trying to modify it, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have the actual files that will be used.. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16K_bwLggfBSY2ew4meyv5h4gewFM6Stw?usp=sharing

Comment: I have used this and am having issues making it work for my created form and doc. I can get it to work on the copied files, but not my new one. Would you be willing to help? @CizRanger

Comment: What type of error message do you get on your created form? What exactly are you trying to do with the Google Doc file?

Comment: I am using the google doc as the body of the email. Once the google form is submitted it is to send an email with some of the form responses to the person that filled out the form. I highlighted the columns in the google sheet of the responses that need to be in the email. I have also put the form question titles in the google doc in {{}}.

Comment: The template has Youtube urls in the code "const topicUrls" and I do not need them. I am not sure how to remove them without breaking the code.